# typescript config property "typeRoots" not working for extending global interfaces

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

The following works on TS 3, but not on TS 4:

```
// src/@types/array.d.ts
declare global {
  interface Array {
    /**
     * @example [["key", "value"]]._toH() ->
     * { key: "value" }
     */
    _toH(): object

    /** returns the last element of the array */
    _last(): any
  }
}

// src/foo.ts
const arr = [1]
arr._toH() // Property '_toH' does not exist on type number[]
```

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "typeRoots": ["@types", "node_modules/@types"],
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "scripts/**/*", ".eslintrc.js", "@types/*"]
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?